# Confusion in calling function (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am learning jQuery UI. I downloaded a code in which the author made a plugin. Code is working but i am confusing when author is calling a function. Here is the code

```
(function($){

    $.widget("ui.calculator", {

        options: {

            autoShow: true,
            currentSum: []

        }, //end of options

        _create: function(){..},
        destroy: function(){..},
        disable: function(){..},
        enable: function() {..},
        show: function() {
            var el = this.element.children(":first");
            if (el.is(":hidden")) {
                el.show();
            }
            this._trigger("show", null, this.element);
        }, //end of show()

         _addHoverState: function(){..}, 
         ..
    }); //end of $.widget()

})(jQuery);
```

and here it is calling the method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //To configure the autoShow option, we could use:
    //To add a handler for the custom show event we defined     
    $("#calc").calculator({
        autoShow: true,
        show: function(e, ui) {
            alert(e + ", " + $(ui).attr("id"));
        }
     });

 }); //end of document.ready(fn)
```

I am confusing in calling. I define show method just **show: function(){}** no argument i am passing. But when calling i am writing **show: function(e, ui) {}** passing two arguments to my show function. Why? Also i debug it in the firebug and i noticed that after **show: function(e, ui) {** line, it comes to _create() method of the plugin , but don't go inside show method. Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two entirely different `show`s. This one:

```
$("#calc").calculator({
    show: function(e, ui) { /* ... */ }
});
```

is a callback function that your calculator widget calls. Somewhere inside your widget you'd say:

```
this.options.show.call(some_sensible_this, e, ui);
```

to call it with whatever context (`some_sensible_this`) makes sense for your widget or if you don't care about the context, you'd just say:

```
this.options.show(e, ui);
```

The `show` that you define with the widget factory:

```
show: function() {
    var el = this.element.children(":first");
    if (el.is(":hidden")) {
        el.show();
    }
    this._trigger("show", null, this.element);
}
```

will be a jQuery-UI style method on your widget that you'd call like this:

```
$('#calc').calculator('show');
```

That "message passing" interface is the usual way of calling methods in the jQuery-UI world; the standard behavior for a jQuery plugin is to return a jQuery object for chaining so it is difficult for a plugin to return a custom object with normal JavaScript methods on it. To have chaining and the ability to call custom methods at the same time, you call the plugin with a method name and arguments:

```
$(...).somePlugin('some_method', arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Look at any of the *Methods* tabs in the jQuery-UI documentation for examples; the [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) has things like this:

> `activate`
>   `.accordion( "activate" , index )`
>
> Activate a content part of the Accordion programmatically.

There's also a third `show` in play here and that's this one:

```
el.show();
```

That `show` is just the usual [jQuery `show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function.

Comment: Hhmmm. I saw the code and i didn't find any line as you said `this.options.show.call(some_sensible_this, e, ui);`. That's why it is not coming inside this method. But in the _create function there is a line `(this.options.autoShow) ?container.appendTo(this.element): container.appendTo(this.element).hide();`. Means if i set `autoShow:false',` then do not append to container. It means neither my **show()** method is calling nor **show: function(e, ui) { /* ... */ }** is calling. After setting `autoShow` option, jQuery UI automatically calling the _create method. Am i right?

Comment: @Basit: `this.options.show.call(some_sensible_this, e, ui);` is just an example of how the callback might be called, I don't know any more about the plugin than your sample so I don't know how it is really called. `_create` is called by jQuery UI as a constructor, `this.options` holds the options passed to `$(...).calculator({...})`. If you set `autoShow:false` then you probably have to `$('#calc').calculator('show')` to get it to show, I don't know when the `show` callback will be called.

Comment: @muOK :). You explained me really well. Yup you just gave me an example but it clears me that why the show method isn't calling. One thing that i want to ask is this i just used jQuery UI tabs in which i used something like this `var tabOpts = {select:function(event, tab){...}};->$("#myTabs").tabs(tabOpts);`. So here i am calling tab callback. Means somewhere in the tab.js plugin there is a line which is like `this.options.select.call(some_sensible_this, e, ui)`. Am i right? Can you tell me what are event and tab in this case that i am passing to my select function? Thanks

Comment: @Basit: Somewhere there is something like that `.call(...)` but it might be hard to recognize. The [tabs docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-select) are a bit sparse, you'll have to `console.log(event)` and `console.log(ui)` to see what's in them.